# Bootstrap tabs-x plugin ajax not loading on page load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

When I load ajax tabs via the bootstrap-tabs-x plugin the first tab does not show on page load. The tab content does show properly when I actually click on the first tab. The plugin expects json encoded html to be returned from the AJAX call but that appears to work since clicking on first or second tabs work perfectly.
How to get the first tab loaded on page load or how to trigger the load?

```
<div class="tabs-x align-center tabs-above tab-bordered">
    <ul id="ltr" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li id="li_ltr_index" class="active"><a id="ref_ltr_index" href="#ltr_index" data-toggle="tab" data-url="ajax1.php">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li id="li_ltr_edit"><a id="ref_ltr_edit" href="#ltr_edit" data-toggle="tab" data-url="ajax2.php">Edit</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="ltr_index"></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="ltr_edit"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: drop the js in here

Comment: Following code for the plugin is used: https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-tabs-x/blob/master/js/bootstrap-tabs-x.js